# String Color change in Outlook Add in using C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, outlook-addin

i am programming in microsoft outlook add in.i want to display some text like "welcome" in outlook Composemail Body.How to i set that string  in different color?

In Javascript:

```
var strval = "welcome";
var strcolor =strval.fontcolor("blue");
var strcolor =strval.fontcolor("eeff");
```

Thanks
Sanju

Comment: i searched in google,it gives only change the color of the text controls like.textbox.forecolor,richtextbox,labels etc.I cant get the string variable fontcolor change.

Comment: IS the JavaScript working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question does not provide much information. If you just want to display a blue 'Welcome' message in the body of your email you can just set it using HTML.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem;

mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body><font color="blue">Welcome</font></body></html>"
```

If you can provide any more information I can update the answer.

Comment: @ Alex : thank u.i already knew that in javascript.i just want to know any options there in c#.

Comment: Okay Sanju no problem :)